# Merge two sorted linked lists.Write a SortedMerge() function that takes two lists,

Tags: c++

Merge two sorted linked lists
Write a SortedMerge() function that takes two lists, each of which is sorted in increasing order, and merges the two together into one list which is in increasing order. SortedMerge() should return the new list. The new list should be made by splicing
together the nodes of the first two lists.

Runtime Error:
Runtime ErrorSegmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)
Learn More about Seg Fault

```
Node* SortedMerge(Node* head1,   Node* head2)
{
    struct Node *result;
   // Node *temp;
   if(head1==NULL)
      return head2;
  if(head2==NULL)
     return head1;
  if(head1->data<=head2->data)
  {
      result->data=head1->data;
     //result=head1;
      result->next=SortedMerge( head1->next,   head2);

  }
  else if(head1->data>head2->data)
  {
       result->data=head2->data;
      //     result=head2;
      result->next=SortedMerge( head1,   head2->next);


  }

  else
  {
      return NULL;

  }





    return result;
    // Your Code Here
}
```

iam getting segmentation fault . why?

Comment: Classic use of an uninitialized pointer Here: `result->data`, `result` doesn't point to anything. You need to create an object for it to point to (or fix take advantage of the fact that you're dealing with non-const linked list and insert items rather than creating a whole result list).

Comment: You should not copy the `data` anywhere, only change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

this line "struct Node *result;" should be "struct Node *result = new Node;". It should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You’re dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.

You’re going in the right direction, but the function should return either `head1` or `head2`, depending on their values, and not copy any `data`.

```
Node* SortedMerge(Node* head1, Node* head2)
{
   if(head1==NULL)
      return head2;
  if(head2==NULL)
     return head1;
  if(head1->data<head2->data)
  {
      head1->next=SortedMerge(head1->next, head2);
      return head1;
  }
  else
  {
      head2->next=SortedMerge(head1, head2->next);
      return head2;
   }
}
```